# Find all Foreign keys of a table and add cascade on delete

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some tables that have the **foreign key** reference. I need to find all the foreign key names in a particular table and add **cascade on delete** option using SQL query.
I don't want to drop my table or delete the data. Some of the tables may have **circular references**.
Is there any solution to do this?

Comment: You shouldn't apply cascade deletes blindly. You need to carefully *plan* your cascade paths and yes, you need to avoid cycles.

Comment: Any suggestion to do this?

Answer (score 0):

below query will help you to find foreign key of a table

```
EXEC sp_fkeys 'TableName'
```

so far i know ,you dont need table drop but 1st you have to drop foreign key , then you have to create it again adding the your expected rule
below is an example

```
GO
ALTER TABLE EmailContact DROP
   CONSTRAINT FK_EmailContact_Email
GO
ALTER TABLE EmailContact ADD
   CONSTRAINT FK_EmailContact_Email  
       FOREIGN KEY (EmailId)
      REFERENCES Email (Id)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: This query will create a new key in the table, I need to avoid duplicate reference.

Comment: @Sajithv you want modify existing key ?

Comment: yes. need to modify existing keys with cascade on delete. but I can't hard code foreign key names within the SQL query, I want to find the name and then need to modify.

Comment: @Sajithv if you want to add rule of existing fk then you need 1st drop that fk then create it again using your rule

Comment: @Sajithv you have to write store procedure 1st find the fk then take it on variable and then have apply my answer portion on that key